# Unable to install a release build of APK

Tags: android, apk, keytool, jarsigner

I created an app that worked well in the emulator and in devices when tested. I then used the export option to generate a signed APK for release. But this APK is not installing and is showing the error message "unable to install" when installed from sd-card. The debug version works well. How should i proceed.

Comment: have you removed the debug version first?

Comment: Does the error say anything other than "unable to install?"

Comment: yes thank's i removed the debug version and reinstalled the signed version and before that i cleared memory now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have installed an app, you can not install another version of that app if it was signed with a different certificate.  You will need to go to Settings and remove the currently installed version.